# Using Vuetify with Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js, laravel-spark

I would like to add vuetify to a new Laravel Spark project. Is this a good? bad? idea?
I'm getting no help from Laracast.
Could someone point me to tutorial to use the latest vuetify with the latest spark or close to latest.

Comment: After wasting many hours on trying to get vuetify to work properly with laravel spark I've given up. I think spark is to tightly coupled to bootstrap which doesn't play nice with trying to use another framework like vuetify.

Here is an example to get vuetify working with a plain laravel install: https://github.com/nekosaur/laravel-vuetify

Let me know if you get it working though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's good, don't be afraid just always go hand in hand with the documentation